# How to center form elements in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

As you can see from my screenshot my form/input are not centered. How do I get them to be centered?

You can see a screenshot here https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O7po.jpg

Comment: show your code, post more details. An image isn't enough.

Comment: The css code is minified since it is jquery mobile. What should I show?

Comment: You might have given `float:right` or `display:block`...anyway post your code...